# Add space to the Ubuntu main partition

Tags: 18.04, gparted, swap

I made a partition on my hard drive to install Ubuntu and thus have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Now I want to allocate more space to Ubuntu and I find a difficulty that is to move the partition with swap, since between the partition in which Ubuntu is and the free space is swap. I tried to move it with GParted but there are still things that I do not understand well. How could I increase the main partition of Ubuntu?

[image: GParted screenshot]

<sub>*This post has been translated from Spanish. Please see the [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1144632/revisions) for the original*</sub>

Comment: To grow or shrink a partition, it cannot be in use, so a 'live' (eg. install media) is the easiest way to grow your partition. The linux swap will need moving to get the space next to sda6 that I believe you want to grow, but I normally just delete swap, then re-create it (and 18.04 can use swapfile so re-creating it is optional as I don't see another OS that would use it on your machine).

Comment: Please note: this site uses english, so your question will be translated by someone here, and any answers will also be in english (or risk being translated to english).  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6853/does-it-make-sense-to-flag-non-english-questions?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Luis Talavera-I think guiverc is correct, that's what your problem is. Do you know how to make a live cd/dvd?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Yes, I know how to make a live CD/DVD

Comment: @guiverc So, I can delete swap and add space to Ubuntu main partition and, I don't need to re create swap file?

Comment: I made a Ubuntu CD Live and resize and move swap and main partition with GParted, everything works fine, thank you all for your help. :D